# unfortunately has stopped working, android studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I'm a complete beginner in Android Programming and I know this has been posted a ton of times already.
The thing is, I have read every post, and I dont seem to have any mistakes like everyone is posting, I think I followed every basic step correctly.
It is supposed to just be logging on facebook for now, nothing more.
I tried running on the native emulator and Genymotion, same result.
It's been 3 days now, it's driving me crazy.

My logcat:

```
11-02 15:24:28.131 1423-1423/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-02 15:24:28.299 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-02 15:24:28.299 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d7db20)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.tasos.likefeed_4, PID: 1423
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.tasos.likefeed_4.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tasos.likefeed_4.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4-1, /system/lib]]
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.tasos.likefeed_4.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4-1, /system/lib]]
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4301) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
11-02 15:24:28.307 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-02 15:24:30.231 1423-1423/com.example.tasos.likefeed_4 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1423 SIG: 9
```

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tasos.likefeed_4" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity:

```
package com.example.tasos.likefeed_4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My MainFragment:

```
package com.example.tasos.likefeed_4;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView myTextDetails;
    private CallbackManager myCallbackManager;

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> myCallback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile!=null){
                myTextDetails.setText("Welcome" + profile.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    };

    public MainFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        myCallbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(myCallbackManager,myCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        myCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your `MyApplication` class under `com.example.tasos.likefeed_4`. If not give the correct package it is residing in or try to remove `android:name=".MyApplication"` from manifest and run it (If MyApplication has no custom stuff in your app).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much it, that was actually it, I feel so stupid for not noticing.